# How to give new methods to an existing object via a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to take an existing instance, keep its old behavior and give it additional methods that are defined in a separate class.

With the code below, you create a matplotlib figure and axes and draw a few points on it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(range(5), range(5))
# Should print nothing.
```

Using my custom class, I would like the base behavior + whatever I defined in the custom class.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = AttentiveAxes(fig, 111)
ax.scatter(range(5), range(5))
# Should print "Just plotted a new <matplotlib.collection.PathCollection>".
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```py
class AttentiveAxes:
    
    def __new__(cls, figure, geometry) -> matplotlib.axes.Axes:
        ax = figure.add_subplot(geometry)
        cls.__init__(ax)
        return ax
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.add_callback(self._on_new_artist_added)       
        
    def _on_new_artist_added(self, artist) -> None:
        print(f"Just plotted a new {artist}.")
```

This throws an error `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute '_on_new_artist_added'` which tells me that the base ax object never "collected" the additional methods defined in the class.

I have tried this too which is absolutely ugly and I'm sure it's the wrong approach.

```py
class AttentiveAxes:

    def __init__(self, figure, geometry):     
        self._ax = figure.add_subplot(geometry)
        self._ax.add_callback(self._on_new_artist_added)
               
    def _on_new_artist_added(self, artist) -> None:
        print(f"Just plotted a new {artist}.")
        
    def __getattr__(self, key:str):
        """Needed to avoid calling `ax._ax.<new_method>` in the main program."""
        try:
            return self.__dict__[key]
        except KeyError:
            return getattr(self._ax, key)
```

I do not think I can simply subclass `matplotlib.axes.Axes` because I do not want to call `Axes.__init__(...)`, I want the provided figure to create an Axes for me via `figure.add_subplot(...)` then modify it.

Comment: off the top of my head I think you probably *should* subclass here, but if you're trying to use composition instead the approach in your `AttentiveAxes` class strikes me as completely unexciting.  Keeping an instance and modifying it is normally done that way: I don't think it's *ugly* at all.

Comment: Note that my reasoning for 'you should subclass' is largely based on the names of your classes and the fact that you seem only to be adding a logging method and want your class to behave like the target.  This reasoning may be entirely spurious ;)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I add more than a logging method but this is just a MRE. The actual work consists in taking note of all the initial dimensions (markersize, linewidth...) of the new artists, respond to resize events of the figure and resize the artists accordingly so that their scale is constant. I'll try the subclassing approach and edit it in the question.

Comment: to my mind "'AttentiveAxes' is [are!] an 'Axes'" makes sense, ergo subclassing.  But if that's a mere quirk of English, composition and modification in __init__ really is fine.

Comment: To be honest, the main reason why I avoid subclassing in this specific context is because I have no clue how `Axes.__init__` works. I have always used a variant of `ax = fig.add_subplot(ijk)` or `axes = fig.subplots(i, j)`.

Comment: Then don't worry about it at all.  Either avoid __init__ at all, or just pass everything up to `super().__init__`.  Just subclass Figure as well, and override add_subplot so that it uses your Axes class (have a look at how it's implemented: it might be simpler to override whatever method is called to get the axes internally).  Then you can code like before.  That's what I'd do, if I understand the problem correctly: you want the figure methods to return an extended Axes class, so you have to lightly override them to do so.

Comment: Note that your question asks about adding extra methods, but your example suggest you want to alter *every* existing method through the use of `__getattr__`. Which can become problematic.

Comment: @9769953 No no, the `__getattr__` part is simply a trick to have access to the new methods (the callbacks for example) and the ones from `Axes` (scatter, plot, legend, ...) from the same object. If you remove `__getattr__` you have to do `ax._ax.scatter`. I want the external use to be no different than with a regular `Axes` so I did this. `ax.<new_method> is ax.<new_method>` but `ax.scatter is ax._ax.scatter`.

Comment: But do you want to add specific methods? Or override specific methods (so they have some logging involved, as in your example)? Or more generic?

Comment: Yes I want to add new methods and not override existing ones. The logging will be done via matplotlib's callback system which is nice and allows us not to have to override anything.